Matrix data not being affecting by the report parameter in report builder
I have a data set in Microsoft report builder and a couple of parameters based on queries.
If I use a simple table both parameters work but when I use a matrix, the child group which should be affected by one of the parameters isn't.
I have tried putting a filter on the tablix properties but either I'm not doing it right or it's not the right place to make it work.
Please help!
